# Can't use dplyr::arrange() to sort a column in the form of a date in r

Tags: r, dplyr, xts

Does anyone know the reason why dplyr's `arrange()` function cannot sort a column who's column name is in the form of a date-like string?

Take a look at the example below:

```
rnames <- LETTERS[1:10]
set.seed(1)
values <- runif(10, 0, 10) %>% 
  round(1) %>% 
  data.frame(., row.names = rnames) %>% 
  `colnames<-`("2022-03-01") 
values %>% dplyr::arrange("2022-03-01")
```

If you run that block of code, you can clearly see that the column did not sort:

```
 2022-03-01
A        2.7
B        3.7
C        5.7
D        9.1
E        2.0
F        9.0
G        9.4
H        6.6
I        6.3
J        0.6
```

There are a variety of ways to fix the code in order to allow for sorting, including, but not limited to: (i) using `dplyr::arrange_all()`, (ii) nesting `dplyr::across()` within the arrange() call, (iii) changing the column name to one not resembling a date, or (iv) using base R's `order()` function in conjunction with brackets.

My question is why the `arrange()` function does not work (without throwing an error) despite the fact that the column is in character form:

```
> typeof(colnames(values))
[1] "character
```

I ask because for people working with stock or other time series data, sometimes dates do become column names and so to the extent they need to sort such columns, this quirk could produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the double quoted column name, use backquote

```
library(dplyr)
values %>% 
   dplyr::arrange(`2022-03-01`)
```

-output

```
   2022-03-01
J        0.6
E        2.0
A        2.7
B        3.7
C        5.7
I        6.3
H        6.6
F        9.0
D        9.1
G        9.4
```

---

If we want to pass as string, either use within `across`

```
values %>%
   dplyr::arrange(across("2022-03-01"))
  2022-03-01
J        0.6
E        2.0
A        2.7
B        3.7
C        5.7
I        6.3
H        6.6
F        9.0
D        9.1
G        9.4
```

Or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
values %>%
  dplyr::arrange(!! rlang::sym("2022-03-01"))
  2022-03-01
J        0.6
E        2.0
A        2.7
B        3.7
C        5.7
I        6.3
H        6.6
F        9.0
D        9.1
G        9.4
```

Or with `.data`

```
values %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(.data[["2022-03-01"]])
```

Comment: Yes, that will work as would any of my other suggestions. There are many solutions to this problem. My question relates to what is going on under the hood that is effectively disallowing seemingly legal character objects from being treated like other character objects.

Comment: @kamiks Only certain function in tidyverse allows to pass column names a strings i.e. one of theem is `select` whereas the majority requires unquoted column name (and here it is a non-standard column name, thus it can be backquoted)

Comment: @kamiks I am not sure whether you have gone through the [tidyverse vignettes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Admittedly, I have not gone through all of the vignettes. And yes, tidyverse did try to coerce me away from creating a column name with a date-like character object (which is why I had to rename my column after the fact). And yes, as per all of the above, there are plenty of solutions to this issue. That being said, I felt it was a good to make the community aware of this quirk.

Comment: @kamiks column names staarting with digits is not standard and this is the reason why `data.frame` or `read.csv` creates the `X` prefix by default `check = FALSE` when dealing with those columns

Comment: If you check `?data.frame` - `check.names -TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are.`

Comment: Makes sense. Much appreciated!